# Wordpress Custom Widget - Saving a list of checkboxes created from custom post types

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, checkbox

This is probably a pretty standard thing to do.  I just can't work out for the life of me how to do it.  I checked various other coded doing similar things but most of them seem to do things in a different way from me which I don't quite understand.

Basically I am creating a simple custom widget.  It pulls in all the post from a post type and displays them as checkboxes.  I need to save which posts were selected and then pass this on as an array so that I can then display the selected posts.

To display the checkboxes in a form I have:

```
$postcount5 = 0; $featured_query5 = new WP_Query('showposts=5&post_type=adverts');
    while ($featured_query5->have_posts()) : $featured_query5->the_post(); 
    $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_ID();$postcount5++;
    $currentid5 = get_the_ID();
    echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="adverts" value="';
    the_id();
    echo'" ';
    if ( $currentid5 == $adboxid ) echo 'checked="yes"';
    echo '/> ';
    the_title();
    echo' </label><br/></p>';
```

Once I have managed to save them I should be fine.  I just cannot work out how to save a list of dynamically created checkboxes.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The code as it is, wouldn't work even if it wasn't dynamically. 
What you need to do is rename the name of the checkboxes too, otherwise only the last value will be accessible. E.g. you could do it like so:

```
$postcount5 = 0; 
$featured_query5 = new WP_Query('showposts=5&post_type=adverts');
while ($featured_query5->have_posts()) : $featured_query5->the_post(); 
   $do_not_duplicate[] = get_the_ID();
   $postcount5++;
   $currentid5 = get_the_ID();

   echo '<p><label><input type="checkbox" name="adverts'.$postcount5.'" value="'.$the_id().'";
   if ( $currentid5 == $adboxid ) echo 'checked="yes"';
   echo '/> ';
   the_title();
   echo' </label><br/></p>';
```

And to finally get the values, you need a submit button and wrap the whole thing into a  with a set 'action' element like:

```
<form name="postselector" action="whereever_you_want_the_user_to_go_next.php">
INSERT HERE ALL THE INPUT CHECKBOXES
AND THE SUBMIT BUTTON
</form>
```

In whereever_you_want_the_user_to_go_next.php you can finally read the selected items by:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $selectedposts = array();
   $i = 0;
   foreach($_POST as $name => $value) {
      if (preg_match('adverts',$name) {
         $selectedposts[$i] = $value;
         $i++;
      }
   }
}
```